# Isn't Dagger 2 for Android is not DI framework, but glorified Service Locator?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

For example, let's say my Rest adapter created with Retrofit lives inside Application class. 
I would love to get it inside the Activity, so I write the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject MyRestAdapter mRestAdapter;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((GlobalApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Granted, it will make the job done. But...
How is this different from calling getApplication(), and then explicitly yank the MyRestAdapter to MainActivity? Yes, Dagger 2 will simplify the setup by automatically getting everything to the Activity, but you still need to explicitly tell from where you need these dependencies, and that, if I understand correctly, defeats the whole purpose of DI. Am I right to say that Dagger 2 is "semi-automated service locator", or it's just the tutorials that misled me, and there is correct way to inject dependencies with Dagger 2 into the View or Activity from Application?

Comment: Well said, Dagger 2 is not the real DI. Most of the tutorial or blogs just jump to a conclusion that you can Inject but ignore that pain about dependency weaving, which contradicts the concepts of IoC design pattern.

Comment: I think your post should have received more attention. Dagger is not dependency injection. It’s a shame developers use the wrong names for things.

Answer (score 5):

I've been experimenting with Dagger and it definitely seems to blur the lines between service locator and dependency injection. This is at least true when used with Android activities. With the current version of Dagger, it is possible to write `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` in an activity's `onCreate` method. That's basically like saying "find all the services I need and inject them into me." So Dagger is a combination of a some central/global service locator that knows where to get the services and an injector that knows where (i.e. which instance variables) to put those services in the activity. It seems that Android activities force reliance on some kind of singleton/global object.

Answer (score -1):

There is no 1 "purpose of DI" but definitely one of them is to separate the configuration from what actually requests the configured objects. The idea is that your higher-level objects, such as `Activity`s in Android, can request all of the objects it needs without worrying about where they come from, how they are constructed, and any semantics about their relationships. Similar to how an `Activity` doesn't deal with drawing text to the screen (and instead delegates that to a `TextView`[0]), DI helps keep your objects from knowing too much that is not relevant to the actual logic they need to perform.

Inherent in the "semi-automated service locator" you describe is static analysis and error handling. As applications become larger, it becomes even harder to get manual-DI correct. Dagger helps make your code less error-prone (and less tedious to maintain).

Consider the case where you have an internal version of your app for employees, where you log lots of information about how they use the app to make sure you can identify any issues. In your actual product, however, you don't want to track personally identifiable information like that when it's not necessary. Now, your `MainActivity` needs an `AnalyticsLogger` - which one should it get? The more cases you have, the easier it is for Dagger to help piece things together than for you to do it yourself.

[0] which delegates to a `Paint` object